# Need a way to gate content on my webpage in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I wanted to gate content on my site using web forms module just like how QUORA/glassdoor does. I would want only logged in users to see all content and non logged in users should be shown a form to fill based on which user should be shown the actual content, have no coding experience. Have a bit of idea on the editor side though.

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict whether content may be viewed by anonymous visitors by changing the setting in /admin/people/permissions > View published content.
By default they will see an "Access denied" message.

There are many ways to achieve redirecting anonymous visitors to a login page or form when they visit a page they don't have access to.
One way would be to use a module like anonymous_login: https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_login

[Screenshot of Home > Administration > People > Permissions > View published content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ddTm.png)